How can I remove all instances of an individual if a condition is met once?
I want to remove individuals from my df that have ANY values below a certain latitude. Specifically if individual "A" is in the dataset three times, and one of those times they are below the set latitude, I want all entries including that individual to be removed. Here is an example of what I want to achieve:
name <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b')
latitude <- c('50', '55', '55', '40', '57', '60')
df <- data.frame(name, latitude)

I want to remove all names with latitudes below 45. "A" has one entry below 45, so remove "A" from the data so it looks like this:
  name latitude
1    b       55
2    c       55
3    b       60

Thus far what I've been doing is this:
df <- df %>% filter(latitude > 45) 
  name latitude
1    a       50
2    b       55
3    c       55
4    a       57
5    b       60

I know that's nowhere near the solution I need, but I had to start somewhere. I'm pretty new with R, so any detailed explanations would also be appreciated.

A base R code-golfing with subset + ave
> subset(df, !ave(latitude < 45, name))
  name latitude
2    b       55
3    c       55
6    b       60


df %>% filter(all(latitude >= 45), .by = name)

  name latitude
1    b       55
2    c       55
3    b       60


df %>% filter(!any(latitude < 45), .by = name)

  name latitude
1    b       55
2    c       55
3    b       60


Base R solution
> with(df, df[!name %in% name[latitude<45], ])
  name latitude
2    b       55
3    c       55
6    b       60

dplyr:
df %>% 
  filter( !name %in% name[latitude<45])


With a data.table anti-join:
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!df[latitude < 45], on = "name"]
#>      name latitude
#>    <char>   <char>
#> 1:      b       55
#> 2:      c       55
#> 3:      b       60

